# Will reverifying a new owner in Google Search Console cause data loss or ranking problems?

Tags: google-search-console, ranking, ownership, site-verification

I want to add a new owner to Google Search Console using re-verification. Will I lose data and rankings if  I do that?

Comment: Are you planning to keep the old owner verified too?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, no impact to the data and ranking result.

The new owner's data have the same data as the old owner's data. Nothing is different.

*Note: I just tried after I read your question.*